# Data Type Mismatch in Criteria Expression

Tags: vba

Data Type Mismatch in Criteria Expression, I thought that this below code was correct but now im getting this error, not sure what i've added that is incorrect.

The below code is posting to a database

And the function Main() just connects to the DB

```
Private Sub adddata()
    Main
    Dim strSQL As String

    Data1 = Sheets("Sticker").Range("B6").Value
    Data2 = Sheets("Sticker").Range("D4").Value
    Data3 = Sheets("Sticker").Range("A2").Value
    Data4 = Sheets("Sticker").Range("C8").Value
    Data5 = Sheets("Sticker").Range("B14").Value
    Data6 = Sheets("Sticker").Range("D12").Value
    Data7 = Sheets("Sticker").Range("A10").Value
    Data8 = Sheets("Sticker").Range("C16").Value
    strSQL = "INSERT INTO STICKER (CertNo, IssueDate, Serial, RecalDue,CertNo_Vic, IssueDate_Vic, Serial_Vic, RecalDue_Vic)" & _
            "VALUES('" & _
            Data1 & "','" & _
            Data2 & "','" & _
            Data3 & "','" & _
            Data4 & "','" & _
            Data5 & "','" & _
            Data6 & "','" & _
            Data7 & "','" & _
            Data8 & "')"

    adoConnection.Execute strSQL, , adCmdText + adExecuteNoRecords
    MsgBox "Added info to the db   ", vbExclamation, "Connection.Execute"
End Sub
```

Comment: Just a guess, but it's probably complaining because you're putting quotes around field values that aren't character.  Also, consider using Prepared Statements -- they help to mitigate this type of problem.

Comment: start by telling us what each DataN is -a number? a string? also what are the database columns data types?

Comment: Every other column is a date within the database, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which DB are you connecting to? Assuming  it's Access, date literals have to be surrounded by # character, not a single quote e.g #7/12/2013#

But a better solution would be to use parametrized query - this way you won't have to worry about proper quotes and simple pass the values as they are. Bonus: that will help to avoid possible SQL injection.