# Data Type Mismatch in criteria expression while trying to select by date

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I am facing the following issue :

> Run-time error `-2147217913(80040e07)`: Data Type mismatch in criteria expression :

I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18316426/11167163) so I tried this :

```
sSQL = "SELECT " & FieldSelect & " FROM Test WHERE Match1= '" & VarMatch1 & "' AND LaDate = '#" & LaDate & "#'"
```

where in my VBA Code

```
Dim LaDate as Date
LaDate = "10/20/2021"
```

And In Access :

```
LaDate : Data Type = Date/Time
```

[image]

But still same issue. so What Am I Missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was `'`

In fact If you encapsulate your date with `#` you do not need to add `'` before.

```
sSQL = "SELECT " & FieldSelect & " FROM Test WHERE Match1= '" & VarMatch1 & "' AND LaDate = #" & LaDate & "#"
```